# EdgeJS on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-ec2, mono

Has anyone gotten this working?  I've got Node installed, I've built Mono, but this is crapping out (trying to follow the Ubuntu instructions [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tjanczuk/edge/mono/tools/ubuntu_12.04_clean_install.sh)).

Currently when executing npm install, I'm getting:

```
[ec2-user@sfr edge-mono]$ sudo -u ${THE_USER} npm install
npm WARN package.json jshint@1.1.0 No repository field.

> edge@0.7.15-pre install /home/ec2-user/edge-mono
> node tools/install.js

Package mono-2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mono-2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mono-2' found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config mono-2 --libs' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:340:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:807:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/edge-mono
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Any ideas - maybe there's a yum package?

Comment: It's not really an answer, but it is a solution - I switched to ubuntu 12.04 and ran [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tjanczuk/edge/mono/tools/ubuntu_12.04_clean_install.sh) script.  Perfect.

Comment: I had a similar issue installing on OS X, but I think the steps will be the same. First [find where your `mono-2.pc` directory is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420931/pkg-config-path-for-mono-on-mac), then update PKG_CONFIG_PATH to include that directory.